# xcode 6.3 Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: xcode6.3, arm64

xcode 6.3 Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

but my libs support arm64

Architectures in the fat file: libavfilter.a are: armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64

and build setting architectures is armv7 arm64, Valid Architectures is armv7 armv7s arm64

Comment: hi , Did you get the solution for this ?